# How to set border and fill as no color on checkbox appearanceStream using pdfbox 2

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to change my background color and fill color of my checkboxes into no color option,

How to change it on below code, Tried with multiple combinations but saving the file with alternative colors. I am new to PDF Box. If I remove these two values my check box itself not loading on the PDF.

Kindly help me out for changing the property value into no color

Here is my sample code,

```
private static void addCBField(PDDocument document, PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, String name, boolean checked,
        float x, float y, float width, float height, String toolTip, List<String> exportList) {

    try {

        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height);

        PDCheckBox checkbox = new PDCheckBox(acroForm);
        checkbox.setPartialName(name);
        PDAnnotationWidget widget = checkbox.getWidgets().get(0);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPrinted(true);

        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(
                new COSDictionary());
        appearanceCharacteristics.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
        appearanceCharacteristics.setBackground(new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 1, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
        // 8 = cross; 4 = checkmark; H = star; u = diamond; n = square, l = dot
        appearanceCharacteristics.setNormalCaption("4");
        widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearanceCharacteristics);

        /*
         * PDBorderStyleDictionary borderStyleDictionary = new
         * PDBorderStyleDictionary(); borderStyleDictionary.setWidth(1);
         * borderStyleDictionary.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_SOLID);
         * widget.setBorderStyle(borderStyleDictionary);
         */

        PDAppearanceDictionary ap = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        widget.setAppearance(ap);
        PDAppearanceEntry normalAppearance = ap.getNormalAppearance();

        COSDictionary normalAppearanceDict = (COSDictionary) normalAppearance.getCOSObject();
        normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.Off, createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(document, widget, false));
        normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.YES, createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(document, widget, true));

    
        page.getAnnotations().add(checkbox.getWidgets().get(0));
        acroForm.getFields().add(checkbox);

        checkbox.setAlternateFieldName(toolTip);
        checkbox.setExportValues(exportList);

        if (checked) {
            checkbox.check();
        } else {
            checkbox.unCheck();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static PDAppearanceStream createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(final PDDocument document,
        PDAnnotationWidget widget, boolean on) throws IOException {
    PDRectangle rect = widget.getRectangle();
    PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics;
    PDAppearanceStream yesAP = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
    yesAP.setBBox(new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()));
    yesAP.setResources(new PDResources());
    PDPageContentStream yesAPCS = new PDPageContentStream(document, yesAP);
    appearanceCharacteristics = widget.getAppearanceCharacteristics();
    PDColor backgroundColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBackground();
    PDColor borderColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBorderColour();
    float lineWidth = getLineWidth(widget);
    yesAPCS.setLineWidth(lineWidth); // border style (dash) ignored
    yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(backgroundColor);
    yesAPCS.addRect(0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    yesAPCS.fill();
    yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(borderColor);
    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth);
    yesAPCS.stroke();
    if (!on) {
        yesAPCS.close();
        return yesAP;
    }

    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth, lineWidth, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
    yesAPCS.clip();

    String normalCaption = appearanceCharacteristics.getNormalCaption();
    if (normalCaption == null) {
        normalCaption = "4"; // Adobe behaviour
    }

    if ("8".equals(normalCaption)) {
        // Adobe paints a cross instead of using the Zapf Dingbats cross symbol
        yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(0f);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.stroke();
    } else {
        // The caption is not unicode, but the Zapf Dingbats code in the PDF
        // Thus convert it back to unicode
        // Assume that only the first character is used.
        String name = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.codeToName(normalCaption.codePointAt(0));
        String unicode = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getGlyphList().toUnicode(name);
        Rectangle2D bounds = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getPath(name).getBounds2D();
        float size = (float) Math.min(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight()) / 1000;
        // assume that checkmark has square size
        // the calculations approximate what Adobe is doing, i.e. put the glyph in the
        // middle
        float fontSize = (rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2) / size * 0.6666f;
        float xOffset = (float) (rect.getWidth() - (bounds.getWidth()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        xOffset -= bounds.getX() / 1000 * fontSize;
        float yOffset = (float) (rect.getHeight() - (bounds.getHeight()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        yOffset -= bounds.getY() / 1000 * fontSize;
        yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(0f);
        yesAPCS.beginText();
        yesAPCS.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, fontSize);
        yesAPCS.newLineAtOffset(xOffset, yOffset);
        yesAPCS.showText(unicode);
        yesAPCS.endText();
    }
    yesAPCS.close();
    return yesAP;
}

private static float getLineWidth(PDAnnotationWidget widget) {

    PDBorderStyleDictionary bs = widget.getBorderStyle();
    if (bs != null) {
        return bs.getWidth();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: remove the `yesAPCS.fill();` line. The problem is that there's still this weird blue color, I think that is by Adobe.

Comment: I commented few lines including the line mentioned by you on the comment. It's working fine as expected. But now on adding up 2 or more checkbox values with same name as a single group checkbox values with different export values. If I try to add multiple checkbox values with the same name causing an issue. First checkbox alone drawing on pdf file. If I change the name then it's loading. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: That's a different topic, please create a new question. Also consider to answer this one yourself and explain what you changed. Also mention where you got the inspiration for the original code 

Comment: ;) @Tilman Hausherr Took code inspiration from your github source only. 
Thanks for you support and I have few more clarity on tagging these form elements if you could help me on this as well or if you have any source references on marking form fields please ping here

Comment: I mean as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting out below mentioned lines it's working as expected,

```
appearanceCharacteristics.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[] { 0.75f }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
appearanceCharacteristics.setBackground(new PDColor(new float[] {0.75f }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
PDColor backgroundColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBackground();
PDColor borderColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBorderColour();
yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(backgroundColor);
yesAPCS.fill();
yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(borderColor);
yesAPCS.stroke();
yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(0f);
```

Thanks for your kind support @Tilman Hausherr